# Python function is not returning any value

Tags: python

```
def ipr_628(a):
    as1=a.split("  ")
    if (as1[0][5:7] == "01"):
        return "m2pa link"
    if (as1[0][5:7] == "02"):
        return "m3ua asp"
import re
arr1=[]
with open ("C:\\Users\\bb0066029\\Desktop\\IPR3.txt","rt") as k:   
    arr=k.read().split("\n")
    arr2=[]
    for j in arr:
        if (re.match("[a-zA-Z|\s]+",j)):
            arr2.append(j.strip())        
    arr3=[]
    arr4=[]
    for l in arr2:       
        if  "0629  SCTP ASSOCIATION TERMINATED" in l or "0628  SCTP ASSOCIATION ESTABLISHED" in l or "0662   SCTP PATH UP" in l :
            str1=(arr2[arr2.index(l)+5])
            print (type(str1))
            print ((ipr_628(str1)))
            t=re.sub("\s+"," ",l)+":"+arr2[arr2.index(l)+5]+":"+str(ipr_628(str1))
            arr3.append(t)
            #arr4.append(arr2[arr2.index(l)+5])
            continue            
    for c in arr3:
        with open("C:\\Users\\bb0066029\\Desktop\\mean.txt","at") as d:
            d.write(c)
            d.write("\n")
            d.close()
```

When I am calling the above function ,in the main program it's returning NONE .Why?
I am expecting a output like `REPT: COMM 0628 SCTP ASSOCIATION ESTABLISHED CTB08:DATA: 01002A%  000001.  030DED%  000A14%  000A0A%  000A14%  000AEA%  010DED%:m2pa Link`

but I am getting None in place of m2pa Link.

Comment: That code is very hard to read, please format it thank you

Comment: None of your if conditions is matching and the function reaches its end which results in an implicit `return None`.

Comment: First you populate arr2 with alpha characters. Then you search arr2 for Alpha-Numeric strings. So, of course, you won't find anything! and since you populate arr3 in that same if statement, you again won't find anything in arr3, since it never gets populated and is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Neither condition is met apparently. If there's a default value that you want to return, maybe you should add a return after the two if conditionals.